# How to remove everything outside of round brackets in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to extract image urls from css file using a notepad++.
Since all the image urls are inside of the round brackets I am thinking about regex to remove everything before ( and everything after ).
Here is a text example :

```
    text-transform:uppercase;

    font-size:17px;

}

.conTxt .btnGiveAccess{

    width:532px;

    height:145px;

    background:url(http://www.website.com/css/images/btn-give-me-access2.jpg) no-repeat center top;

    margin:0 auto;

    display:block;

}

.conTxt .btnGiveAccess:hover{

    background:url(http://www.website.com/css/images/btn-give-me-access2.jpg) no-repeat center -145px;

}

/*#########################################*/
popup window
/*#########################################*/
/*a {
```

As a result I woul dlike to get the following:

http://www.website.com/css/images/btn-give-me-access2.jpg

http://www.website.com/css/images/btn-give-me-access2.jpg

I also tried the following regex to delete everything before http://

```
^[^http]*`  Also .*((.*)).*
```

but it didnt work. Could anybody please help?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but might help: http://superuser.com/questions/477628/export-all-regular-expression-matches-in-textpad-or-notepad-as-a-list

Answer (score 1):

For the given text the following works. Use a find text of `(\A|\))([^()]*)(\(|\Z)` and replace that with `\r\n`. This will leave the required text plus a few empty lines that can easily be removed, eg by menu => **Edit** => **Line operations** => **Remove empty lines**.

A minor variation is to use a replacement string of `\1\3`. which will remove everything outside the round brackets leaving the brackets themselves and the text between them. It is then a simple job to remove all round brackets, perhaps replacing them with new lines. This could be done with a find text of `[()]+` and replace string of `\r\n`.

Explanation of the first regular expression. The captures are:

1. `(\A|\))` which looks for either the start of the buffer, the `\A` or a close bracket.
2. `([^()]*)` which looks for a sequence of characters that do not include round brackets.
3. `(\(|\Z)` which looks for a close bracket or the end of the buffer, the `\Z`.

The effect is to look for a three types of text.

1. From start of buffer to first opening round bracket. This matches `(\A)([^()]*)(\(|\Z)`.
2. From close bracket to open bracket. This matches `(\))([^()]*)(\()`.
3. From close bracket to end of buffer. This matches `(\))([^()]*)(\Z)`.

This may not do the desired job if there are nested round brackets, but the question does not specify what should happen in such cases.

Comment: Thank you sooo very much. The regex worked as a charm.

Comment: Happy to help you @MichaelAlbertson. Stack Overflow has a Q&A format. Please read the help pages and, in particular, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Wow, this is great and clean code, easily repurposed. I was able to drop it into a Namemangler concatenate function and rename 220 files which had their real name put into round brackets with the first line of text in front of the brackets but missing the closing bracket sometimes. 

```[concatenate
 [findRegularExpression
  "(\A|\))([^()]*)(\(|\Z) "
  in <name>
  replace with ""
 ]
 <.extension>
]``` It did remove the round brackets, leaving me with just the file names with the existing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the URLs have parens in them, you could use `\((.*)\)`

The difference between this and what you show above is that the outer `()` (the literal ones, not the ones that make the regex capture) are escaped using `\`

Comment: Thank you for a reply. This code deleted everything but a single paragraph. URLS and all